# Reliable way to open an editor in the command prompt cross platform?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to open a temporary file in a command line editor that I can read from on exit. I have a working solution for operating systems that have `vim` installed - but not all operating systems come with `vim` by default and I'm not aware of a universal editor that is available on all platforms. I'd like to be able to provide this functionality, without the user having to download a specific editor. Below is a snippet of my current solution.

```
import os
import tempfile

from subprocess import call

editor = os.environ.get("EDITOR", "vim")

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("r+", suffix=".tmp") as temp_file:
    temp_file.write("Initial message.")
    temp_file.flush()

    call([editor, temp_file.name])

    temp_file.seek(0)
    edits = read_edits(temp_file) # Reads changes to the temp file.
```

As you can see from the snippet above - if the `EDITOR` environment variable is not set by the user, `vim` is used, but if `vim` isn't present on the operating system, an exception is thrown. How can I make this work without worrying about what editors users have installed?

Comment: [\[Python\]: Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) ? Or how would you expect it to work when there's no editor present?

Comment: @CristiFati Maybe I wasn't clear but I'd like to actually allow the user to use an editor, I could catch the exception but then what? I'd rather not loop through every possible editor.

Comment: *edit* is another option (*Lnx* and *Win*). Anyway you should probably start assembling your editor list. But anyway there are lots of *OS*es, and I think the problem might be a bit too broad.

Comment: `vi` for all unix systems, `edit` for 32-bit windows. For 64-bit windows you're out of luck.